# CodeCommit: Trigger vs Notification when branch is deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want **SNS** when branch is deleted. What to use? `CodeCommit Trigger` or `CodeCommit Notification`?

Trigger can be activated with branch deletion and Notification can be activated by branch delete also. What to select and why? Help me understand.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use both triggers/notifications but point to note is **Triggers** do not use **CloudWatch** Events rules to evaluate repository events.

Refer - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-repository-email.html

> Although you can configure a trigger to use Amazon SNS to send emails
>   about some repository events, those events are limited to operational
>   events, such as creating branches and pushing code to a branch.
>   Triggers do not use CloudWatch Events rules to evaluate repository
>   events.

Answer (score 1):

**CodeCommit trigger**

Choose trigger if you are interested in **one specific branch** (or few named branches; up to 10) being deleted.

**CodeCommit Notification**

Setup notification if you want to get notified about **any branch in your repository** being deleted.